# Запуск illustrator из Photoshop

Tags: photoshop, jsx, illustrator

Есть ли способ вызвать illustrator из Photoshop используя скрипты?

Comment: зачем? можно смарт объекты использовать - они напрямую связывают два редактора.

Comment: для автоматизации